# Entity embed data align class

Tags: 8, entities

I am using drupal core 8.4.2 and lightning 8.x-2.23. I can embed images inside Ckeditor using entity embed. I need to change the name of the data align class from this:

```
<figure="embedded-entity align-right">
```

To this:

```
<figure="embedded-entity floated-element float-right-sm">
```

Where is the class name align-right coming from and how can I change it?

Comment: I will try to explain more. This file: core/modules/filter/templates/filter-caption.html.twig. Print this out:<figure{%- if classes %} class="{{ classes }}"{%- endif %}>. and the {{ classes }} is where align-right is. How can I add or remove classes here?

Comment: That will most likely be somewhere in CKEditor's JS config that core provides, or possible in drupalSettings in #attached somewhere in the core.